# unable to understand how can i calculate sum of digits using 4 digits

Tags: permutations, summation

How can I calculate sum of 4 Digit no. which can be formed by Using {0,1,2,3} when repetition is not allowed.

Comment: What is the question exactly? The no. of 4 digit no.s possible ? Or their sum?

Comment: actuallly We have to calculate Sum of $4$ Digit no. which can be formed by Using $\{0,1,2,3\}$ when repetition is not allowed Thanks

Comment: Check the edit to my reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a set of 4 digits, to be filled in four places `- - - -`; you have a total of $4 * 4 * 4 * 4 = 256$ possibilities.

But, you can't put `0` at the thousand's place; thus it reduces to: $ 3 * 4 * 4 * 4 = 192 $.

Again, we move to next case of not having repetitions; total cases(with and without zero): $ 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 24 $

Removing zero from first place: $ 3 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 18 $.

---

## Edit

Since you mentioned that you need the sum, and not the count of numbers, here goes:

Cases with first digit `3` = 6.

$$\text{Sum of all 3XYZ} = 3 * 6 * 1000 + (1 + 2 + 0) * 2 * 100 + (1 + 2 + 0) * 2 * 10 + (1 + 2 + 0) * 2 * 1 = 18666 $$

Similar approach will give us:

$$ \text{Result} = 18666 + 12888 + 7110 = 38664 $$

The result is 38664

Answer (score 1):

Total permuatations of these 4 digits = $4!$

But, it includes cases when $0$ is at first position which gives $3$-digit numbers, so we have to exclude those cases and no. of such cases= $3!$ (as $0$ is fixed on first position)

Thus total $4$-digit numbers using these digits without replacement= $4!-3!=24-6=18$

Answer (score 0):

The first digit cannot be $0$, so there is $3$ possibility there. The next one can't be the first one, but can be $0$, so there is again $3$ possibility there. Then $2$ possibility for the 3rd digit, and $1$ possibility for the 4th. All in all,
$$ 3\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1$$
4 digits numbers are there.

Answer (score 0):

Totally there are 3*2*1 4 digit no.s beginning with 1.The 2nd digit is 1 for 2*2*1 cases. The 3rd digit is also 1 for 2*2*1 cases. The same for the 4th digit. The situation is the same for 2 and 3.

So the sum of no.s  is (3*2*1*1000+2*2*1*100 +2*2*1*10+2*2*1)(3+2+1)